# Facebook breaking local currency changes for September 12, 2013

Tags: facebook

I have an application already using local currencies with FB Credits.

I'd like to see what code changes I need to make (and ONLY the code changes I need to make) to my app so that it conforms to the breaking changes; I can't seem to find this information on Facebook's website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to http://developers.facebook.com, select "Apps" from the menu on top, and select your app from the sidebar. One of the widgets you now see should be "Developer Alerts", with the "Breaking Changes" as one of the options. If you select that, you'll see a summary of changes that might affect your app specifically.

Also, you can go directly to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[your app ID]/alerts

If the alert isn't showing up for the local currency changes yet, I suggest you [read the FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/local_currency_faq/) and follow the instructions there to see what might apply  to your app.

> Q: Is this a breaking change?
>
> A: We will migrate all game developers on Facebook.com to local
>   currency payments by September 12, 2013. You will have a minimum of 90
>   days to integrate the payments system. Please review the [updated
>   payments infrastructure](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/) to learn how to update your application before
>   September 12th.

Also read more on [Migrations](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/migrations/):

> You can change a migration to "Enabled" to see what effect that
>   month's changes will have on your app and until the scheduled date of
>   the change, you can "Disable" the migration as well.